# Income Tax in India for variable Income

Tags: income-tax, india

I have variable income through freelance developing software like for e.g say I earn Rs 15lakh in one year and Nil in the next year. Is there any way to distribute the income over two years or any other way to save on taxes

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no such way. Once needs to pay the tax on 15 lacs for the first year and file a NIL return in subsequent year.